# ¿Como buscar con varias columnas en una tabla hasta encontrar el valor en otra tabla?, ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g

Muy buenas, alguien sabe como podría realizar una búsqueda entre dos tablas, donde la primera tiene varias columnas y buscar con todas esas columnas hasta encontrar un resultado en otra tabla, me explico:

Tabla1

```
| nombre | telefono1 | telefono2 | telefono3 |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| usuri1 |    123    |    321    |   456     |
```

Tabla2

```
| telefono | dato1 | dato2 | dato3 |
|----------|-------|-------|-------|
|   555    |   1   |   2   |   2   |
|   456    |   2   |   5   |   3   |
```

Necesito buscar por todas las columnas de teléfono (telefono1, telefono2, telefono3) hasta encontrar un resultado en la Tabla2 y devolver el resultado una vez encontrado.

Comment: y qué pasa si la tabla 2 tiene los 3 teléfonos?

Comment: @Lamak seleccione según el orden de las columnas, para este caso, solo seleccionar para telefono1 y devolver el resultado

Comment: y cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: @Lamak el resultado esperado es que busco por telefono1 en la tabla2 y traigo el resultado si no encuentro nada busco por la columna telefono2 y si no por la columna telefono3 y así hasta encontrar datos en la tabla2, en caso de que no coincida por ninguna simplemente no devuelve nada

Comment: sí, me refiero a cuando dices "traigo el resultado", significa que quieres todas las columnas de la tabla 2?, algún dato de la tabla 1?. Por favor sé más explícito con la info que quieres

Comment: @Lamak si, todos los datos de la tabla2 junto con la columna nombre de la tabla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TELEFONO,DATO1,DATO2,DATO3 FROM (
            SELECT T2.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T2.TELEFONO ORDER BY NULL)DUPLICADOS FROM TABLA2 T2
            WHERE EXISTS (
                            SELECT * FROM TABLA1 T1                
                            WHERE 
                            (  
                               T2.TELEFONO = T1.TELEFONO1
                            OR T2.TELEFONO = T1.TELEFONO2
                            OR T2.TELEFONO = T1.TELEFONO3
                            )
                         )
         )WHERE DUPLICADOS=1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono su solución planteada

Answer (score 1):

Pues la verdad, en este momento no se me ocurren muchas formas que no tengan que recorrer las tablas varias veces. Probablemente hay mejores formas de hacerlo, pero esta es una alternativa:

```
SELECT  t1.nombre,
        t2.telefono,
        t2.dato1,
        t2.dato2,
        t2.dato3
FROM Tabla1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2
    ON t1.telefono1 = t2.telefono
UNION ALL
SELECT  t1.nombre,
        t2.telefono,
        t2.dato1,
        t2.dato2,
        t2.dato3
FROM Tabla1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2
    ON t1.telefono2 = t2.telefono
    AND t1.telefono1 <> t2.telefono
UNION ALL
SELECT  t1.nombre,
        t2.telefono,
        t2.dato1,
        t2.dato2,
        t2.dato3
FROM Tabla1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2
    ON t1.telefono3 = t2.telefono
    AND t1.telefono1 <> t2.telefono
    AND t1.telefono2 <> t2.telefono
;
```